# writing a loop to go through a large list with sublists and save these sublist

Tags: r

I would like to extract data from large list with many sub-lists called 'summary' https://www.dropbox.com/s/uiair94p0v7z2zr/summary10.csv?dl=0

This file is compilation of the fitting of dose response curve by patient and drugs. I share a small file with just 10 patients, 105 drugs and x and y as readout for the fitting with each 100pt. 
I would like to save all the fits for each patient and every drug in a separate file.

I tried to write the list into a df to use tidyverse but didn't manage. I have only started out with R so this is very complex for me.

```
for (i in 1:length(summary10))
{for (j in 1:length(summary10[[i]]))
{x1 <- summary10[[i]][[j]][[1]]  
y1 <- summary10[[i]][[j]][[2]]
print(summary10[[i]][[j]]);}}
```

the loop works but I don't know how to save them in different files so that I will be able to know what is what. I tried something I found online but it doesn't work:

```
for (i in 1:length(summary10))
{for (j in 1:length(summary10[[i]]))
{x1 <- summary10[[i]][[j]][[1]] 
y1 <- summary10[[i]][[j]][[2]] 
cbind(x1,y1) -> resp
write.csv(resp, file = paste0(summary[[i]], ".-csv"), row.names = FALSE)                          
}}
```

> `Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :   invalid 'description' argument 
>   In addition: 
>   Warning message: In if (file == "") file <- stdout() else if (is.character(file)) { :   the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`

Answer (score 1):

It's really hard to anticipate what goes wrong, when we cannot see how you made `summary10`. No way am I going to guess how you came from your tabular file, to a list of lists (or whatever `summary10` may be).

But in the end, your error indicates that you are providing an illicit filename in the `file = paste0(summary[[i]], ".-csv")` argument. First tip on debugging is simply printing to console. Try this on for size:

```
cbind(x1,y1) -> resp
cat(paste0(summary[[i]], ".-csv", '\n')   # <----- 
# use `cat` to print to console the contents of your expressiosn
write.csv(resp, file = paste0(summary[[i]], ".-csv"), row.names = FALSE)
```

What is it? It should evaluate to a simple string, say `B.M.21.S.-csv`, but it might not be the case.

At a first glance, I would guess you've misspelled your variable. `summary` is usually a function, whereas you might be looking for `summary10`. Still, the i'th element of `summary10` looks like it could be a list itself, so your expression will fail to produce a simple string.

---

## Update with `summary10`

I always recommend using `str` to examine the structure of an object. For lists, use the argument `max.level` to avoid printing endless nested lists:

```
> str(summary10, max.level=1)
List of 10
 $ B-HR-25 :List of 106
 $ B-SR-22 :List of 106
 $ B-VHR-01:List of 106
 $ B-SR-23 :List of 106
 $ B-SR-24 :List of 106
 $ B-HR-21 :List of 106
 $ B-M-21  :List of 106
 $ B-SR-21 :List of 106
 $ B-MR-01 :List of 106
 $ B-M-01  :List of 106
```

And then a step further in:

```
> str(summary10[[1]], max.level=2)
List of 106
 $ PP242             :List of 2
  ..$ x: num [1:100] 1 1.1 1.2 1.32 1.45 ...
  ..$ y: num [1:100] 0.923 0.922 0.921 0.92 0.919 ...
 $ AZD8055           :List of 2
  ..$ x: num [1:100] 1 1.1 1.2 1.32 1.45 ...
  ..$ y: num [1:100] 0.953 0.953 0.953 0.952 0.952 ...
```

So object `summary10` is a collection of patients (lists of lists); `summary10[1]` is the collection containing the first patient, `summary10[[1]]` the first patient (a list itself) with their responses to drugs.

So what happens when you try to make a filename from `summary10[[i]]`? Try it, I won't print the output here. Back to `str(summary10)`, the patients' designations ("B-HR-25", etc.) are the *names* of the entries. Get them with `names(summary10)`. As an exercise, compare `names(summary10)`, `names(summary10)[1]`, `names(summary10[1])` and `names(summary10[[1]])`.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions and sorry for not being concrete enough: summary10 is also a list that I created by summary[1:10] -> summary10 . summary$patient(for example.B-M-21)$drug (for example PP242)$x. I share now the .RData file so that you understand better: https://www.dropbox.com/s/13ac8d0isu2z79k/summary10.RData?dl=0 o  Iwould like to for each patient [i] in summary10 I would like save the fits for drug k to a file that contains the i-j in the name and the fit x,y in the file itself. I would be very happy for any input.